# Using Clojure's data structure with MapDB

Tags: clojure, mapdb

I tried to use directly Clojure's hashmap with MapDB and ran into weird behaviour. I checked Clojure and MapDB sources and couldn't understand the problem.

First everything looks fine:

```
lein try org.mapdb/mapdb "1.0.6"

; defining a db for the first time
(import [org.mapdb DB DBMaker])
(defonce db (-> (DBMaker/newFileDB (java.io.File. "/tmp/mapdb"))
                .closeOnJvmShutdown
                .compressionEnable
                .make))
(defonce fruits (.getTreeMap db "fruits-store"))
(do (.put fruits :banana {:qty 2}) (.commit db))

(get fruits :banana)
=> {:qty 2}
(:qty (get fruits :banana))
=> 2
(first (keys (get fruits :banana)))
=> :qty
(= :qty (first (keys (get fruits :banana))))
=> true

CTRL-D
=> Bye for now!
```

Then I try to access the data again:

```
lein try org.mapdb/mapdb "1.0.6"

; loading previsously created db
(import [org.mapdb DB DBMaker])
(defonce db (-> (DBMaker/newFileDB (java.io.File. "/tmp/mapdb"))
                .closeOnJvmShutdown
                .compressionEnable
                .make))
(defonce fruits (.getTreeMap db "fruits-store"))

(get fruits :banana)
=> {:qty 2}
(:qty (get fruits :banana))
=> nil
(first (keys (get fruits :banana)))
=> :qty
(= :qty (first (keys (get fruits :banana))))
=> false
(class (first (keys (get fruits :banana))))
=> clojure.lang.Keyword
```

How come the same keyword be different with respect to `=` ?
Is there some weird reference problem happening ?

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with mapdb. `(def k? (first (keys (get fruits :banana))))` `(= k? (keyword (name k?)))` => `false`

Comment: Taking another look - mapdb isn't specifically made to support Clojure datatypes. I am not at all surprised the native generic java serialization tools don't really do Clojure keywords properly. I think this is similar to the classic problem with serializing booleans and false not working properly. You may want to clj-mapdb (though it is still in beta, API in flux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the way equality of keywords works. Looking at the
implementation of the [`=` function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Util.java#L24) we see that since keywords are not
`clojure.lang.Number` or `clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection` their equality is
determined in terms of the `Object.equals` method. Skimming the [source of
`clojure.lang.Keyword`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Keyword.java) we learn that keywords don't not override
`Object.equals` and therefore two keywords are equal iff they are *the same
object*.

The default serializer of MapDB is `org.mapdb.SerializerPojo`, a subclass of
`org.mapdb.SerializerBase`. In [its documentation](http://www.mapdb.org/apidocs/org/mapdb/SerializerBase.html) we can read that
it's a

> Serializer which uses ‘header byte’ to serialize/deserialize most of classes
>   from ‘java.lang’ and ‘java.util’ packages.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that well with `clojure.lang` classes; It doesn't
preserve identity of keywords, thus breaking equality.
In order to fix it let's attempt to write our own [serializer](http://www.mapdb.org/apidocs/org/mapdb/Serializer.html) using the
[EDN format](https://github.com/edn-format/edn)—alternatively, you could consider, say, [Nippy](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/nippy)—and use
it in our MapDB.

```
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn])

(deftype EDNSeralizer []
  ;; See docs of org.mapdb.Serializer for semantics.
  org.mapdb.Serializer
  (fixedSize [_]
    -1)
  (serialize [_ out obj]
    (.writeUTF out (pr-str obj)))
  (deserialize [_ in available]
    (edn/read-string (.readUTF in)))
  ;; MapDB expects serializers to be serializable.
  java.io.Serializable)

(def edn-serializer (EDNSeralizer.))

(import [org.mapdb DB DBMaker])
(def db (.. (DBMaker/newFileDB (java.io.File. "/tmp/mapdb"))
            closeOnJvmShutdown
            compressionEnable
            make))

(def more-fruits (.. db
                     (createTreeMap "more-fruits")
                     (valueSerializer (EDNSeralizer.))
                     (makeOrGet)))
(.put more-fruits :banana {:qty 2})
(.commit db)
```

Once the `more-fruits` tree map is reopened in a JVM with `EDNSeralizer` defined
the `:qty` object stored inside will be *the same* object as any other `:qty`
instance. As a result equality checks will work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the sources references and explanations. It's funny though that  `clojure.lang.Keyword` implements `Comparable` which makes this correct :
`(.compareTo :qty (first (keys (get fruits :banana))))`

Comment: I'm not clear on how the `edn-serializer` var is used by the MapDB API. Could you extrapolate on that a bit more?